# htaccess is working but does not replace the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I'm trying to modify the subdomain name in the URL to make it look nicer. My current URL look something like:

```
www.mystore.com/productInfo.php?cPath=11_11&productID=222
```

So, I want to make it nicer by Rewrite in .htaccess in main with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^productInfo/([0-9_-]+)/([0-9_-]+) productInfo.php?cPath=$1&productID=$2 [NC,L]
```

When I run and test it on the URL by typing `www.mystore.com/productInfo/11_11/222` in the URL it works well. However, when this page is redirected by a different page or is 'refreshed' with a self redirecting `a href=` link(in which the link is written in php by the previous programmer), the above old link is still visible in the URL instead of the new one.

I am still a beginner while I suspect that I might need to change something in the cPanel/Apache(I think) for this but currently, I am still do not have access to the cPanel control. Is there anything that I might have missed to write in the .htaccess file or I really do need the cPanel control or any other reasons?

Any help is appreciated. Sorry that I could not find similar questions on this.

Comment: _"I'm trying to modify the subdomain name in the URL"_ - not really, your question does not involve any manipulation of any "subdomain". _"However, when this page is redirected by a different page or is 'refreshed' with a self redirecting a href= link(in which the link is written in php by the previous programmer), the above old link is still visible in the URL instead of the new one."_ - you _can_ implement an additional redirect that redirects those "old" URL formats to the new ones -

Comment: - but this should rather be fixed in the actual code, those system-issued redirects and links should contain the _proper_ "new" format already. Otherwise, you will be forcing every visitor of such URLs to make _two_ requests instead of one each time. (And when it comes to tools such as Google PageSpeed, they won't particularly like that either.)

Comment: - CBroe, when I hover over the redirect link, the old format is still shown in bottom left/right browser(depends on mouse cursor placement). Is this what you meant when URL makes 2 requests?

Comment: This would be causing two requests, if you implemented what Amit suggested in the given answer, and _redirect_ those old formats to the new, "fancy" ones first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect /productInfo.php?cPath=foo&productID=bar to /productInfo/foo/bar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /productInfo\.php\?cPath=([0-9_-]+)&productID=([0-9_-]) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ productInfo/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
#rewrite new URL to the old one
RewriteRule ^productInfo/([0-9_-]+)/([0-9_-]+) productInfo.php?cPath=$1&productID=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, the URL now becomes `www.mystore.com/productInfo/11_11/222?cPath=11_11&productID=222` when the `?cPath...` should have been removed.

Comment: @AsnadAhmad  Sorry There was a slight typo. I have fixed it. Please clear your browser caches and use the edited code.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava Sir! I have updated the answer as per your suggestion. 

Comment: Thank you @Amit Verma ! The solution has worked for me. Would you care to explain why is there a \ after the `.php` ? Isn't it sufficient if there is only one \ after `productInfo` ?

Comment: @AsnadAhmad The \ is there to escape the `?` . In regex `?` is treated as a special character. If you don't use the backslash before a special character then the pattern will treat the URL differently.